# Change position of text over a card image: Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap card and I want to place a text over the image. So I have this:

```
<div className ="container" id="mainContainer">
  <div className ="row mt-4">
    <div className="col-md-4">
      <div className="card" >
        <img  className="card-img-top bg-light mb-3" alt="" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png">
         </img>
         <div className="card-img-overlay">
           <span className="badge badge-dark"> 1 </span>
         </div>
         <div className="card-body">
           <h5 className="card-title"> Bulbasaur  </h5>
           <span className="badge badge-light"> poison </span>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like this
[image: what I want]

but I currently have this[image: what I have]

There are many things different as you can see, but the most important one is the position of the element - I can't get it where I want.

Comment: You must have some custom CSS here? Please share all of the relevant code.

Comment: I don't have any custom CSS that applies here

Answer (score 0):

```
             <div className ="row">
                <div className="col">
                  <div className="card">
                    <img  className="card-img-top bg-light mb-3" alt="" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png">
                     </img>
                     <div className="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" style={{ padding: '0px'}}>
                       <span className="badge badge-dark" style={{ width: '30%'}}> 1 </span>
                     </div>
                     <div className="card-body">
                       <h5 className="card-title"> Bulbasaur  </h5>
                       <span className="badge badge-light"> poison </span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

You could probably change a few things in here but this seems to work.